# Change screen dimensions - windows 7

Tags: windows-7, display, resolution

The bottom fourth of my screen is broken, showing some weird lines. It's too expensive for me to replace it, but there's still plenty of space in the upper part because it originally had full HD resolution (1920x1080).

What I wanted to try is to change the size of the screen that Windows 7 uses, i.e. somehow trick it into believing my screen physically is smaller, by one fourth of it's height. That way the windows would nicely fill the working screen space when maximized, etc.

I'm sure this can be done, but how complicated is it?

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the monitor.  Some support display of exact pixel resolutions without stretching, and also allow advanced positioning of the displayed resolution, instead of centering. What graphics chip and monitor do you have?  Have you considered perhaps getting a nice secondhand monitor?

Comment: Yeah, I found the option of customizing the resolution, but strange enough, not the one to fine tune the screen position, so when I switch to the smaller resolution, the top part of the screen is left unused. I'll try finding a new driver, maybe there's an option of doing that.

Comment: Try flicking or tapping directly on the lines, my monitor had the same problem, now it's gone ever since I flicked at the lines! It simply is just a few lcd cells that are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Most monitors have a vertical position setting. This will allow you to move the picture up, might not get you all the way though.

Apart from that you could stretch your task bar so it takes up most of the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

¾ of 1080 would be a 810. If you can set a custom resolution of 1920x810 then that should do the trick.

But first test it with the well supported resolution of 1024x768.

There are a few things which can happen:

1. Your display puts the image in the left upper corner.
2. Your display centres the display.
3. Your drivers stretch the image.

---

Case 1 would look like this. It is the desired goal.

[image: 1920x1080 and 1024x768 at one fourth scale]

---

In case 2 the centering is done by the display itself. 
You can usually disable that in the monitors menu's.

---

In case 3 the driver detects that you are not using all the the screen real estate and stretches the image until it is large enough to fill all of the screen. This is a driver option and disabling this depends on which driver you use.

On the case of AMD/ATI cards you can disable this via the Catalyst control center. Matrox, Nvidia, Intel and other brands have their own drivers but similar capabilities.

[image: Screenshot of CCC with GPU scaling screen marked]

---

Once you tested that 1024x728 works, try defining the 1080x810 resolution (and fine tune that until you use all of the still working screen parts.)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response. As I said above, I found the option of customizing the resolution, but not the one to fine tune the screen position yet...I probably need to update my Intel driver. It's a laptop screen, so like most of them it doesn't have the buttons for that kinda stuff.
I'm sorry i can't give you a vote up :)

Comment: Some laptops have an option in the BIOS called 'stretch screen' or 'fill screen'. If it is there, turm that to the off position.